# exchanging partial derivative and an integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, partial-derivative

Does  $\frac{\partial  }{\partial x}\int_{u(x)}^{v(x)}f(x,t)dt$  = $\int_{u(x)}^{v(x)}\frac{\partial  }{\partial x}f(x,t)dt$ ??

If yes, how did we do that although there are 2 functions $u$ and $v$ in the integration limits?

Here is a screenshot from a book that made me confusion
[image]

Comment: You are missing terms of the form $f(x,v(x)) { \partial v(x) \over \partial x} - f(x,u(x)) { \partial u(x) \over \partial x}$ on the right hand side.

Comment: I would prefer that, but let me post a screenshot of a book

Comment: @copper.hat see the screenshot

Comment: They use something like $I(x,u,v) = \int_u^v f(x,t) dt$. The partial with respect to $x,u,v$ are more or less as above, then consider the function $\phi(x) = I(x,u(x),v(x))$ and apply the chain rule.

Comment: @copper.hat what makes me a confusion is not the whole process, but only the last step. He exchanged the derivative and the integral although the limits are not constants.

Comment: Yes, the step is incorrect, or at best, very sloppy from a notation perspective. With my definition, you have ${\partial I(x,u,v) \over \partial x} = \int_u^v {\partial f(x,t) \over \partial x} dt$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $I(x,u,v) = \int_u^v f(x,t) dt$. Suppose $f$ is sufficiently smooth, for example $f$ and ${\partial f(x,t) \over \partial x}$ are continuous.

Then ${\partial I(x,u,v) \over \partial x} = \int_u^v {\partial f(x,t) \over \partial x} dt$, ${\partial I(x,u,v) \over \partial u} = -f(x,u)$ and
${\partial I(x,u,v) \over \partial v} = f(x,v)$.

Now let $\phi(x) = I(x,u(x),v(x))$, then the chain rule gives
${\partial \phi(x) \over \partial x} = {\partial I(x,u(x),v(x)) \over \partial x} + {\partial I(x,u(x),v(x)) \over \partial u}u'(x) + {\partial I(x,u(x),v(x)) \over \partial v}v'(x) $.

Expanding gives:
${\partial \phi(x) \over \partial x} = \int_{u(x)}^{v(x)} {\partial f(x,t) \over \partial x} dt +
f(x,v(x)) v'(x) - f(x,u(x))u'(x)$.